# AutomoSpeaker exploded - auto

Tags: vehicle

My car speaker exploded.

The volume was all the way down to zero, but there was a sudden and explosive boom. Now the speaker rattles and my ears hurt for a couple of days.

Videos from others have shown a tendency for water to leak into the door in this model, which is then ineffectively routed away from the speaker, usually leading to speaker corrosion.

It's my guess a short occurred.

Is a maker at fault for a design which can lead minor rainfall to cause ruination to vehicle components and pain to the operator and passengers? (Or does this fall under standard wear and tear?)

Comment: Hello!  Welcome to Law.SE.  Please read our [tour page](https://law.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: You would need some kind of expert(s) to testify to the faulty design. After that you would have to prove that the design was known to be faulty. After that you could either do a class-action lawsuit or a single suit.

Comment: Jurisdiction? The EU has a two-year product warranty as a standard.

Answer (score 2):

We really can't tell given your description, but it sounds like the product was defective, in which case the manufacturer would have some liability. Supposing that you decided to sue them, the defendant would no doubt argue that it's not their fault, it's yours (at least in part) by not removing water flowing inside your car (??), or the fault of the car manufacturer for making a leaky car; or it could be that your car is so old that it leaks; or that the speaker was so old that it is unreasonable to expect it to still function the way it was designed to. Maybe it was defectively installed. Assuming that you can prove that they were negligent in manufacturing the speaker, you might be awarded damages, including some compensation for pain and suffering. If you ask for a million dollars, you probably will get substantial legal resistance. Your attorney can advise you what's a reasonable figure where they will think "It's better to just settle".

The videos of similar problems could signal larger problems for the company (class action).

Comment: Sounds about right. 

Year: 2014, Mileage: 72k.